# How to fix "attempt to index a nil value and call method "

Tags: lua

I may need some help on this, as newby in this thing i tried to import a my script but i've been blocked with this message " attempt to index global 'strategy' (a nil value)"  and "attempt to call method 'set_stop_loss' (a nil value) both in line 2 and 4

cann someone help fixing this code please ?

```
function Init()
    strategy:name("Ma stratégie")
    strategy:type(1)
    strategy:set_stop_loss("Equity", 1.0, 0.0)
    strategy:set_take_profit("Equity", 1.0, 0.0)
    strategy:CCI(50)
    strategy:MA("fastMA", 0, 50)
    strategy:MA("slowMA", 0, 200)
end

function OnCalculate(index)
    local fastMA = core.indicators:create("SMA", source.close, 50)
    local slowMA = core.indicators:create("SMA", source.close, 200)
    local stopLoss = core.indicators:create("ATR", source, 14)
    local targetProfit = source.close[index] + (source.close[index] - stopLoss.DATA[index]) * 2
    
    if index == 0 then
        stopLoss:setStream(core.Bar(), stopLoss.DATA)
        targetProfit:setStream(core.Bar(), targetProfit.DATA)
    end
    
    local buySignal = (fastMA.DATA[index] > slowMA.DATA[index] and fastMA.DATA[index - 1] <= slowMA.DATA[index - 1])
    local sellSignal = (fastMA.DATA[index] < slowMA.DATA[index] and fastMA.DATA[index - 1] >= slowMA.DATA[index - 1])
    
    if buySignal then
        local stopLossLevel = source.low[index] - stopLoss.DATA[index]
        local takeProfitLevel = targetProfit
        strategy:entry("Buy", strategy.long, nil, source.close[index])
        strategy:order_stop("Buy", stopLossLevel, stopLossLevel)
        strategy:order_limit("Buy", takeProfitLevel, takeProfitLevel)
    elseif sellSignal then
        local stopLossLevel = source.high[index] + stopLoss.DATA[index]
        local takeProfitLevel = targetProfit / 2
        strategy:entry("Sell", strategy.short, nil, source.close[index])
        strategy:order_stop("Sell", stopLossLevel, stopLossLevel)
        strategy:order_limit("Sell", takeProfitLevel, takeProfitLevel)
    end
end
```

importing this script into my compilation trading station

Comment: Which environment - what is your "compilation trading station"? Clearly there is no `strategy` global variable (so `strategy` is `nil`), which is why this isn't working.

Comment: Your code sample is missing the thing that is mentioned in error message. Why is `strategy` expected to exist? If it is expected to be made available by the software that uses your script - what is that software?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback guys, the software is Fxcm trading station. So I need to find what the global variable for it to make it work or what